# Reading mass storage device : Mac failed, Windows succeed. NOT FORMAT ISSUES

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, finder

My question is different and is not an easy one. Please help me. Thank you so much.
Information on my storage device :

```
2TB, 1TB for exFAT, 1 TB for NTFS.
USB 3.0
```

Everything WAS working FINE until today when SUDDENLY my Mac OS X can't read my seagate mass storage device anymore. When I attached it to my Mac, it did mounted correctly. However, when I double clicked its icon to access the contents of its filesystem, the Finder of Mac went not responding. So I switched to access its contents through command line and type the following commands:

```
cd /Volumes/myDevice
ls # here I did get the informations of the items under the root directory
cd aFolder # here I tried to enter a sub-directory, but the shell went not responding, just like the Finder.
```

So I doubted if the filesystem on my mass storage device was corrupted. But when I attached it to a Windows 10 PC, everything works fine. I don't know why Mac failed.

I tried the safe mode of Mac, and it did not help. When I was about to give up and format that mass storage device on Mac through device utilities, it gave me the unexpected information that it can not open the device. I tried to work around this by accessing this device on the Windows 10 virtual machine on my Mac, but it failed and did not work like a Windows 10 PC.

Now I am totally lost. I haven't try the method to entirely format the device on another PC because I think this may be fixable. However, I did try to format one partition, and Mac can't access it either. So I try a entirely different USB device formatted in FAT32, and Mac can access it.

Now I am totally lost. I don't know why Finder went not responding. Any ideas? Thanks so much. I am using Mac OS X Yesomite 10.10.5.

Comment: Have you installed a filesystem driver? Things like https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/

Comment: @Louis Yes! I installed the paragon NTFS driver. I forget to mention it in this article that I also uninstalled paragon NTFS driver in order to solve the problem. But after uninstalling, the mass storage driver still can't be accessed by Mac.

Comment: @Louis I tried attaching my massive storage device to another Mac on which paragon NTFS for mac is not installed, and Finder freeze too. Any suggestion are greatly appreciated!